# Google spreadsheet validation if statement

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I've used validation to create a drop down list of things that will require different values. So in the next column I want to create a formula that checks if anything has been selected in the list (otherwise show nothing e.g ""). Then if a certain item has been selected, multiply it by a certain value, say 2 and then display the total.

Comment: So, what is your question? And what did you try so far?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I tried using a array forumla (=ARRAYFORMULA(IF())) along with the isblank function but that wouldn't work as even when a drop down wasn't selected it was "FALSE". I can't seem to find the right function to check what has been selected. Sorry about clarity issues.

Answer (score 0):

`=if(isblank(A1);"";A1*2)` will return blank if A1 is blank and twice the value in A1 otherwise. If by `a certain item` you mean only one of the valid items is to be doubled, then please instead try `=if(A1=x;A1*2;"")` where `x` is the 'certain item' value.